# Does the order of a IQueryable stay in the actual query in C# EF Core?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

So when I write a query for a DbContext does the order of the queryable actually represent the output query. For example:

```
_dbContext
.Table
.OrderBy(i => i.Date)
.Take(25)
.Where(i => i.Variable == "something")
.ToList()
```

versus

```
_dbContext
.Table
.Where(i => i.Variable == "something")
.OrderBy(i => i.Date)
.Take(25)
.ToList()
```

So these queries are different because the first takes the last 25 items by date and performs a where clause. But the other one takes 25 from the result of the where.

Will this stay in this order when it get's executed or is this like a builder where all properties are set and executed.
If I look at plain SQL there is no way for me to `TAKE` before the `WHERE` in the same query. So it makes sense to me that is wouldn't.

---

The reason for my confusion is that if I would write the first query in MS SQL we would get this:

```
SELECT TOP 25 * FROM `Table` WHERE `Variable` = 'something' ORDER BY `Date`
```

Which takes 25 from the where result.

Comment: You can't really make an apples to apples comparison between an `IQueryable` and a SQL statement.  The SQL that EF generates may look nothing like your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable logging SQL, you will see that order matters for these two queries

```
 SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Date], [t].[Variable]
  FROM (
      SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [m].[Id], [m].[Date], [m].[Variable]
      FROM [MyObjects] AS [m]
      ORDER BY [m].[Date]
  ) AS [t]
  WHERE [t].[Variable] = N'something'
  ORDER BY [t].[Date]
```

and

```
SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [m].[Id], [m].[Date], [m].[Variable]
      FROM [MyObjects] AS [m]
      WHERE [m].[Variable] = N'something'
      ORDER BY [m].[Date]
```

Logging can be enabled by setting log level for EntityFramework Core in appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

Also you need to make sure your db context has this specific constructor overload

```
public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
}
```